# Vendor Directory on Google App Engine go111 runtime causes error?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to get a little setup going and I'm encountering a strange issue. Code here: https://github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo

I can deploy that, as long as I dont have my dependencies vendored locally. Once I let dep populate the vendor directory, I have a strange issue:

> copied /Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/jsoniter.go to /var/folders/q3/x4rq343n57x5v8pccndssw3r0000gn/T/tmp8Crxax/tmpPZJdtd/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/jsoniter.go
>   2018/11/07 09:51:09 Staging second-gen Standard app: unable to copy root directory to /app: unable to copy dir "/Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor" to "vendor": unable to copy dir "/Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com" to "vendor/github.com": unable to copy dir "/Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com/json-iterator" to "vendor/github.com/json-iterator": unable to copy dir "/Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go" to "vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go": unable to copy dir "/Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/skip_tests" to "vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/skip_tests": unable to copy dir "/Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/skip_tests/array" to "vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/skip_tests/array": unable to stat /Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/skip_tests/array/skip_test.go: stat /Users/manuelzapf/go/src/github.com/SantoDE/appenginedemo/vendor/github.com/json-iterator/go/skip_tests/array/skip_test.go: no such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using dep? If so, have you tried deleting the /vendor folder and Gopkg.lock file and re-running `dep ensure`?

Comment: Yeah, did that already a coupe times. Sadly it didnt change the situation at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out on my own. The issue was not with GAE, but instead with dep. Somehow, dep managed to lock in a very old version of that dependency with a symlink beeing in place which of course couldnt be resolved locally. Editing Gopck.toml and point it to a proper revision solved that issue.

Sorry for thinking its a google issue. I dont know to close that question :)